# angular-translate: Translate dynamic value

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

We're using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) to translate our app.

Regular translations with dynamic number values are no problems, like

```
'LIVES_LEFT': 'You have {{ lives }} left.'
```

used like

```
<p>{{ 'LIVES_LEFT' | translate:player }}</p>
```

The problem comes when the dynamic value is a string that itself needs to be translated, like

```
'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD': 'You have a {{ gender }} that is {{ age }} years old.'
```

Used like

```
<p>{{ 'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD' | translate:child }}</p>
```

`gender` in this case should end up resolving to 'boy', or 'girl' if the selected language is English, and for example 'Junge', or 'Mädchen', if the selected language is German. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Partha Sarathi Ghosh below I tried

```
<p>{{ 'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD' | translate:(child | translate) }}</p>
```

But I get a syntax error from that:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]].
```

However,

```
{
    'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD': 'You have a {{ gender | translate }} that is {{ age }} years old.',
    'GENDER_BOY': 'boy',
    'GENDER_GIRL': 'girl'
}
```

used like

```
<p>{{ 'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD' | translate:vm.childTranslationData() }}</p>
```

with Controller code like this:

```
function childTranslationData() {
    return {
        gender: vm.child.gender === 'boy' ? 'GENDER_BOY' : 'GENDER_GIRL',
        age: vm.child.age
    };
}
```

worked great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It may solve your problem.

```
{{ 'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD' | translate:(child | translate) }}
```

Or you can try this

```
'YOU_HAVE_A_CHILD': 'You have a {{ gender | translate }} that is {{ age }} years old.'
```

If does not solve then translate child from your  controller first