# Translate dynamic values with angular 5

Tags: arrays, json, angular, dynamic, translate

I have a json translation file for english and one for german.

They look like this

**en.json**

```
"COLORS": {
        "BLUE": "Blue",
        "RED": "Red",
        "GREEN": "Green"
}
```

same for the german one.

I have a person object and this has an array colors []. A person could have the colors blue and red. Then it would look like this:

```
person.colors[0] = "BLUE";
person.colors[1] = "RED";
```

As you can see, I saved the keys of the translations in the array and not the values.

Now I'm looping through the person's colors like:

```
<div *ngFor="let color of person.colors">
    <p>{{'COLORS.color' | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

But I'm getting no output. What could be the problem?

I already looked at this post [angular-translate: Translate dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223457/angular-translate-translate-dynamic-value) but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try This way

```
<div *ngFor="let color of person.colors">
    <p>{{'COLORS.'+color | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the key as an output like BLUE or red.. but I need the values

Comment: yes i know. It will work if you configured translation properly because i already tried above syntax

Comment: I am also using this and I tested it with other translations and it works. I think it would also have to work for this scenario but I don't know how. I should translate the key and then giving the value of it as output.

Comment: In your code, TranslateModule.forRoot() in app module or shared module, It should in app module

Comment: TranslateModule.forRoot() in app module and use Translate module in shared module without forRoot().It should be done in this way(https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kk1mud-zkq6zp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I looked at it but it couldn't help me at all :/

Comment: will you make demo plunker or stackblitz?